There are no parallel vector fields on Einstein manifold with non-zero scalar curvature.
Here is one of my homework questions:
Let $(M^m,g)$ be a connected Einstein manifold, $m \geqslant 3$. If the scalar curvature $\rho\neq 0$, show that there are no parallel vector fields on $M$.
We may write $X=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, hence $X$ parallel is equivalent to:
$$ X^i_{,k}=\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^k}+X^l \Gamma_{kl}^i =0\quad (k=1,\dots,m)$$
and the  scalar curvature $\rho\neq 0$ is equivalent to
$$ S=\frac{\rho}{m} g \quad \rho=const\neq 0 $$
I have no idea how to proceed, to relate "parallel" to the scalar curvature. Any hints or references are welcomed. Thanks!

Curvature appears only when you covariantly differentiate a vector field twice. The condition of parallel involves only one derivative of the vector field.

This has the flavor of a Bochner theorem. What are you studying in class?

@TedShifrin Thank you Professor, I haven't learn Bochner theorem in class, but only some basic properties of Ricci tensor and scalar curvature. Later we discussed harmonic forms on Riemannian manifold.

@TedShifrin http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/16S-RiemGeom/Notes/Lec27.pdf Excuse me, is this the theorem you mentioned?
